# FPDF error on magento order PDF print

Tags: php, magento, pdf, fpdf

I have problem with my magento store when I wanna print out the sale order report as PDF and  I get this message

**FPDF error: Unsupported image type: com/media/catalog/product/no_selection**

it only happen with the order that the customer didn't choose additional image which (I guess) might be from media/catalog/product/no_selection directory.

I have looked up on the internet to look for solutions but the one I found didn't tell me which PHP file should I fix.

If you have any idea about this problem, I would be appreciated with any answer.

Thank you,
Scott